# Docker volume does not delete a file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container, docker-volume

We are using docker volume to store some static files from the docker host's folder. When I restart the container the files which are updated/added in the host directory I can see the changes in docker volume.
However, when I delete a file from host machine. The file is not getting deleted. I have to use docker volume as this is a shareable resource.
Following is my docker compose file

```
version: '2'
volumes:
  test-volume: {}
services:
  test:
    image: test-volume:test1
    volumes:
      - test-volume:/var/myapp
  test-gateway:
    image: test-gateway:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes_from:
      - test
    volumes:
      - ./test-gateway/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    environment:
      - SITE_ROOT=root
      - SITE_ROOT_ROUTE_FROM=/
      - SITE_ROOT_ROUTE_DIRECTORY=/var/myapp/static
```

So, if I remove any file from myapp and restart the docker container the file is not getting deleted from the docker volume.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve. Are trying to mound of folder on the host as a docker volume?

Comment: I am trying to share the folder from test service with other containers/services.

Comment: There are no other containers defined in the file you posted. You should post the whole file.

Comment: @Sebastian please take a look at it.Now my docker compose is complete

Answer (score 0):

In you compose file you are creating a named volumes `test-volume`. This volume is references in the `test` and `test-gateway` services.

This volume has nothing to do with folders on your docker host. Therefore you cannot delete files on the host and expect this will be reflected in your named volume.

In case you want to map a folder on your docker host your need to use the syntax you used for mapping `conf.d` file.

```
volumes:
  - ./some_folder_on_host:/some_folder_in_container
```

Comment: if I add a new file to the folder on host machine or change the content of the file they are reflecting in the docker volume.